# Wordpress site with Story theme, Stella translation Not supported?

Tags: css, wordpress, multilingual

I am using Wordpress along with the story theme for this website. I have installed the Stella plugin for multiple language support. It works fine when translating the content in the pages, but when it comes to things like "Custom Page title" (see image), which is part of the story theme, it will not translate as I switch between English and German. Is there anyway to fix this or is the stella plug in just not compatible with my theme?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin called "Poly-lang" which is compatible with most themes, including story.